# How to configure and use JanusGraph +Hbase+ Solr?

Tags: solr, hbase, janusgraph

My colleagues have the following problem: I can't find a way to link Janus + HBase + solr

-I managed to get janus + hbase up, using the gremlin console from JanusGraph-0.5.2

- Install Solr
  I would need to link all three together.

Comment: Do you start JanusGraph with bin/gremlin.sh or with bin/janusgrapj-server.sh. Did you check the conf/janusgraph-hbase.properties configuration example? Do you have a SOLR service up and runnng?

Comment: I start JanusGraph with bin/gremlin.sh since I'm working on version 0.5.2. I have also checked the parameters in the example file of conf/janusgraph-hbase-solr.properties. On the other hand, I consume the Solr service in HTTP mode. The problem is that it doesn't work together for me.

Comment: Do you use solr-7.x as prescribed in the JanusGraph compatibility matrix for v0.5.y, https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.5/changelog/? If so, please add the (relevant parts) of the stacktrace you get from gremlin console.